# Extensions Method trying to call protected methods / wrong exhibition of dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a class named `NIFERepository`. It contains a `SaveObject` method, which returns nothing and performs an operation on a database.

```
public class NIFERepository<E>
{
    protected void SaveObject(object saveObject)
    {
        if (saveObject is E)
            this.RepositorySession.Merge(saveObject);
    }
}
```

1 . I wish to create a public extension method who calls this `SaveObject()` method, like this:

```
    public static class NIFERepositoryExtensions
    {
        public static T Save<T, E>(this T self, E saveObject) where T : NIFERepository<E>
        {
            self.SaveObject(saveObject);
            return self;
        }
    }
```

But the protected scope doesn't allow my extensions method to recognize it.

Is there a way for me to get a method of this form to work?

2 . I created my extension method with 2 types: `T` and `E`. `T` is the instance who called it, and `E` is the defined type into my `ProductRepository<Product>`, for example. When I call this method, the defined type is not shown.
[image]

Is there a way for me to get this to work?

Comment: `SaveObject()` should be generic, or at the very least should probably throw an exception if called with the wrong type.

Comment: I don't typed here, but my SaveObject() is throwing an exception when the object parameters is of the wrong type. But I would want my extension method beauty, showing the right type into the call of it. But it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Do not edit answers into the question.  If you have an answer to your own question than post the answer as *an answer*.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add implement this extension method as an actual public member of the class itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You cannot use extension methods to violate encapsulation.
   If the class does not expose the method, you can't call it (except with Reflection).
   The method is (hopefully) `protected` for a reason; you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I thought Extensions methods recognized all types of scope from extended classes. I'll try another way here, thanks!

Comment: @Kiwanax Extension methods are not different than calling a static method. Just a syntatic sugar.

Comment: Really haha. Do you see another way to do what I want? the SaveObject() method could be recognized into extension methods but not in normal instances, like the example above?

Comment: @Kiwanax: No; that is not possible.

Comment: @Kiwanax: It sounds like you actually want `public void SaveObject(E obj)` in the class itself.

Comment: Actually, it appears to be more of an implementation detail of the extension method internals.  I'd say since an extension method is no less related to the extended class than a subclass, why not provide protected access?  Again, this looks like more of a limitation of the C# implementation of extension methods than a conscious decision to prohibit protected access.

Comment: @ScottMcKinney: No.  Derived classes can only access protected members _through a qualifier of their own type_.  Extension methods do not create their own type, so it does not make sense to allow protected members.

Comment: Right, which is why I said, " it appears to be more of an implementation detail of the extension method internals."

Answer (score 2):

Protected method are visible inside inherited classes.
So do inheritance and create a public method that calls the base protected method like

```
public class BaseClass
{
  protected void SomeMethod()
   {

   }
}

public class ChildClass:BaseClass
{
  public void SomeMethodPublic()
        {
          base.SomeMethod()
        }
}
```

Comment: It's a little confusing to use the `base` keyword in a situation like this. The `SomeMethod` is not overridden og hidden in `ChildClass`, so personally I would use `this.SomeMethod()` or (more often) just `SomeMethod()`.

Comment: This is an old thread but I had to comment.  Using base.SomeMethod() is the acceptable call because the method is in the base class.  using this.SomeMethod(), although does work, is the confusing way because it implies that SomeMethod is in the current class.